# Convert specific list of strings cells into multiple rows and keep the other columns

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-explode

I have pandas dataframe that looks like this:

| label | pred | gt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| label1 | val1 | val11 |
| label2 | ['str1', str2'] | ['str1', 'str3', 'str4'] |
| label3 | foo | box |

And I want to convert label2 row where I have lists of strings or None value to multiple rows (in case it is a list of strings):

| label | pred | gt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| label1 | val1 | val11 |
| label2 | 'str1' | 'str1' |
| label2 | str2' | 'str3' |
| label2 | None | 'str4' |
| label3 | foo | box |

I have used `explode()` for this purpose but I get new dataframe with all nan values and the 'exploded' rows are not matched to the right label. Here is my code:

```
df_filtered = output_df[output_df['label'] == 'label2']

# explode the list column into multiple rows while keeping other columns
df_exploded = pd.concat([
    df_filtered.drop(['pred', 'gt'], axis=1),
    df_filtered['pred'].explode().reset_index(drop=True),
    df_filtered['gt'].explode().reset_index(drop=True)
], axis=1)

# add prefix to the existing column name (label) to differentiate each new row
df_exploded = df_exploded.add_prefix('new_')

# rename the columns to remove the prefix from the original column
df_exploded = df_exploded.rename(columns={'new_pred': 'pred', 'new_gt': 'gt'})

# combine the exploded dataframe with the original dataframe, dropping the original list column
df_combined = pd.concat([output_df.drop(['pred', 'gt'], axis=1), df_exploded], axis=1)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) independently and [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) the de-duplicated rows:

```
cols = ['pred', 'gt']

others = df.columns.difference(cols)
out = pd.concat([df.explode(c)[others.union([c])]
                   .assign(n=lambda d: d.groupby(level=0).cumcount())
                   .set_index(['n']+list(others), append=True)
                 for c in cols], axis=1
               ).sort_index(level=[0, 1]).droplevel(1).reset_index(others)

print(out)
```

Output:

```
    label  pred     gt
0  label1  val1  val11
1  label2  str1   str1
1  label2  str2   str3
1  label2   NaN   str4
2  label3   foo    box
```

Comment: I get this error: InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

Comment: Your original index must be non duplicated (`df = df.reset_index(drop=True)`). If this is not the case prepend a unique index to it and discard it in the end ;)